# Multiplying 2 Variables Together in Django

Tags: python, django

Hey so I'm looking to multiple (or add, any aggregation function really) the values of 2 django querysets together. I have tried this multiple ways and I am still running into a number of errors such as

```
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/paymentamount/
Django Version:  2.1.2
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'
```

MODELS:

```
class List(models.Model):
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default=None)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, default=None)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    trim = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, default=None)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default=None)
    drivetrain = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default=None)
    seats = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    kilometers = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    ....
   tier1book = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
   tierid = models.ManyToManyField('TDTier')

class TDTier(models.Model):
    listid = models.ManyToManyField('List')
    bank = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, default=None)
    tier = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    frontendltv = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
    backendltv = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
    interest = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
```

VIEWS:

```
def payment(request):
    item = List.objects.all()
    item3 = List.objects.values_list('tier1book', flat=True)
    item6 = TD.objects.filter(
        list__year=F('year'), 
        kmbottom__lte=F('list__kilometers'), 
        kmtop__gte=F('list__kilometers')
    )
    item7 = TDTier.objects.filter(
        list__year=F('year'),
        tier=('5 Key')
    ).values_list('frontendltv', flat=True)

    item8 = item3 * item7

return render(request, 'paymentamount.html', {'item8':item8})
```

I get that trying to add 2 lists together does not work, however, Pythonic solutions do not seem to be working in Django (a for loop for example). The solution also seems possible if I do a raw SQL query but I am trying to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output of multiplication of two lists with possibly different number of elements?

Comment: The 2 querys are set up in such a way that they will always have the same number of elements (n,n).

Checked the duplicate @markwalker_ but it looks like that only answers what to do if the queryset is from the same model. My question is referring to 2 querysets from 2 models. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, what is the expected result in this case? An element by element multiplication? A matrix multiplication?

Comment: Element by element multiplication. So anther way to look at it would be 

item8 = item3[0] * item7[0]
item8 = item3[1] * item7[1]

another way to look at it would be item8.append() so I am creating a list of the values that have been multiplied together

Comment: What's wrong about: `item8 = [x*y for x, y in zip(item3, item7)]`?

Comment: THAT WAS THE ANSWER! Post that as an answer so i can upvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong about: item8 = [x*y for x, y in zip(item3, item7)]? – schwobaseggl Nov 30 at 16:27

This is the right answer! Trying to give @schwobaseggl credit.

Thanks!